# How to change font size in UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I'm trying to change font size and color in UIDatePicker. To changed colour I used UIDatePicker().setValue(_, forKey: _) and it was enough. I thought that changing size fill be also that easy, but keyPath "fontSize", "textSize" and other don't work... Someone know what is a keyPath for fontSize in UIDatePicker and how to find every keyPath for some classes?

Cheers,
Jakub

Comment: `fontSize` is a parameter of `UIFont` not `UIDatePicker`

Answer (score 5):

You actually can't change the appearance of a `UIDatePicker`:

> You cannot customize the appearance of date pickers.

- UIKit User Interface Catalog

And from the [documenation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker):

> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.
>
> You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout.
>   Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their
>   intrinsic content size.

You would have to create your own custom date picker.